# Help choosing modern replacement for Hitachi 1SS86 Schottky diode

Tags: diodes, microwave, schottky, detector

I’m trying to find a modern Schottky diode to use instead of the 1SS86 Schottky diode (Hitachi version, specifically). I want to use it along with a low current LED to build a lectenna that works for 2 and 5 GHz signal detection. Apparently only the Hitachi version of this diode works for reasons I don’t understand. I do not have experience with Schottky diodes so I’m not sure which specs to focus on when trying to find a modern (I.e., still being manufactured) equivalent. Any help will be greatly appreciated. - Thanks!

Comment: For those who may want to help, here's the Hitachi information: [Hitachi 1SS86 datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9xLW.png). But basically, it's claim to fame appears to be a guaranteed maximum of \$C=850 \:\text{fF}\$ at \$1\:\text{MHz}\$. [This ebay seller](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1SS86-SCHOTTKY-DIODES-HIGH-SENSITIVITY-HITACHI-NEW-2-PIECES/264806388104?epid=1850704655&hash=item3da7b0d188:g:-WsAAOSwS3JeaP51) appears to have some of the Hitachi originals for sale. Though it appears, not an unlimited supply.

Comment: There seems to be a nice whitepaper on the topic, [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN_1807_PL32_1808_132434_RF%20and%20microwave%20power%20detection%20-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46265f064ff0166440727be1055). They include several BAT-series diodes -- all of which would seem suitable to me without thinking much about it. Their specs look better than the 1SS86.

Comment: No problem. I hope you have great success with the project!

Answer (score 1):

Visit the site:

https://www.nrl.navy.mil/Careers/STEM/LEctenna-Challenge/

They found the following solution:

"NTE112 Schottky diode* (preferred) or 1N5711 Schottky Diode (NOTE: Chanzon 1N5711 diodes do not appear to behave the same as the ST Microelectronics 1N5711 and won’t work. Other good alternatives are the Hitachi 1SS106 and NTE583.)"

I tested other Schottky diodes from Chanzon like the 1N6263, and it was painful to get a very dim light on red low-current LED in a dark environment while uploading massive data from my cell phone to my computer.

I think for uploading, I used: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer

And for getting more strong Wi-Fi pulse, I used: https://github.com/neilsorkin19/wifiswitcher

(I think due to the Android update police regarding controlling WiFi, this APK will crash on newer devices? I am not sure about that!)

Anyway, I am working on this topic for months. And I took another approach. Because I couldn't find a diode better than the 1SS86, I hope to code an app for iOS and Android. I will publish links to the App at:

lectenna.app

The video that shows that may the 1SS86 is even better than 1SS106, I recommend to you to watch:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHVmJ5lD9jc

It clarifies that with the classical design, you will need to have different antenna lengths on the LEctennas for 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz.

My final tip is testing a LEctenna with a smartphone to use 2.4 GHz because it is more robust and get as far away as you still can upload enough data.

http://cross-copy.net/

Cross-copy is a useful website for doing tests on the LEctenna as I did:

https://twitter.com/Vollesir/status/1290191982980030466

Just set a password and send the following string from your mobile or tablet to the internet.
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

This string produces quite a lot of data or better-said signals for your LEctenna.

I hope that it helps you a bit. Feel free to contact me.

Comment: Thanks very much, Sirius!